# Unity 2.0 System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, aggregation, unity2.0

Using a Unity 2.0 xml file, I am trying to populate an object that contains a generic list.  According to the Unity Configuration Schema, the array element is only supported.  Has anyone ever tried to use unity to populate a generic list?

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this limitation, in the constructor or with a setter:

```
public class MyService : IMyService {
    List<IMyDependency> _myDeps;

    [Dependency]
    public IMyDependency[] Deps { 
       set {
          _myDeps = new List<IMyDependency>(Deps);
       }
    }
    ...
}
```

If you can not change your class you can still use a factory.